# How to use the output of randint in an if statement (Python)

Tags: python, random

I'm learning Python (3.6.3) and making a silly (and very linear) chatbot to get started. At one point the chatbot asks you to guess its age, I used randint to generate a number between 1-1000 and want to use the outputted random integer in an if statement (so the chat bot is either happy or upset by your answer, depending on whether you thought it was older than it really is).
The user's input is a var called guess and I assumed (as I cannot find a similar example online) that I could just reference guess and the randint in an if statement to print the desired output, but I get an error advising radint is not defined when I run the prog -

```
    print('guess how old I am')
    guess = input()
    import random
    for x in range(1):
        time.sleep(0.4)
        print ('nope, I\'m ' + (str(random.randint(1,1000))) + ' actually')
        time.sleep(0.88)
    if randint <= guess 
        print('(so rude...)')
    else:
        print('aw thanks')
```

Apologies if my StackExchange syntax is broken too, any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: there's a colon missing after the randint <= guess, also you need to import time

Answer (score 0):

```
- you need to define your randint variable
- import time
- fix: you left out colon after "if randint <= guess"
- you need to make your input guess an integer in order to perform comparison

print('guess how old I am')
guess = int(input())
import random
import time
randint = random.randint(1,1000)
for x in range(1):
    time.sleep(0.4)
    print ('nope, I\'m %s actually' % randint)
    time.sleep(0.88)
if randint <= guess:
    print('(so rude...)')
else:
    print('aw thanks')
```

Comment: thanks so much, Larry!
- this is my major error I guess, so randint is defined outside of the if statement and then referred to in it as %s ? Can you please explain the syntax there; what does %s actually do and why is that string followed by % randint? (I thought % was modulus..?)
- time is imported earlier, sorry should have mentioned that.
- goddamn colon
- making the input an int, of course..

Comment: "%s" is for string formatting.  It serves as a placeholder for a variable

You can learn more [here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting)

Answer (score 0):

here is a corrected version of your chatbot:

```
import time
import random


guess = input('guess how old I am: ')
random_guess = random.randint(1,1000)
time.sleep(0.4)
print ('nope, I\'m {} actually'.format(random_guess))
time.sleep(0.88)
if random_guess <= guess:
    print('(so rude...)')
else:
    print('aw thanks')
```

I'm just going to note down the things that were wrong and some good practices so that you can follow it since you are learning python (I just learnt it as well):

1. In the if statement you were comparing `randint <= guess` which is not possible because randint is not saved as variable anywhere. The 1st time you used `random.randint(1, 1000)` it was statically added only to be used in the print statement. So what I did here is save the `random.randint(1,1000)` *(as you can see randint is a method inside the random module of python)* into a variable called `random_guess` for comparison. It returns a random integer as stated in [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint).
2. Coming to the print statement since your `random_guess` will be of
   type `int`, using formatted string will be a nice and pretty option.
3. Always use import statement at the top of the file so that it'll be
   a one stop place for altering imports.
4. Take a look at this `input()` method as well, I have passed in a
   string which automatically prints out the string passed instead of a
   separate print statement
5. I also removed the for loop since it was looping once anyways (I
   know you need to call it many times, anywho..)
6. Edit: Oh, and you missed a colon in the if statement!

I hope this cleared your doubts.

Comment: thanks! Two answers to my question with two different methods is really helping me understand how I need to be using input and how to use in expressions. appreciate your help!